# React Forms: Updating the UI based on the Axios GET call response in withFormik()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, formik

I'm using `withFormik()` for building a form in my Gatsby application.

Currently, I'm making a GET call using `axios` in `withFormik()`'s `handleSubmit()` function. Once I get the response, I should be able to update it on UI.

Problem here is, the data is getting updated on UI after two Clicks on the Search button instead of updating right away after the click.

Could anyone please help and let me know what I'm doing wrong here? Apologies if the question sounds silly.

Here is the excerpt of my code.

```
import React from "react"
import { withFormik, Form, Field } from "formik"
import axios from "axios"

const FormComponent = ({ values, errors }) => (
  <div>
    <Form>
      <label># </label>
      <Field className="HashtagInput" type="text" name="hashtag" />
      <button className="SearchBtn" type="submit"></button>
    </Form>
    <p className="SearchResult">{values.hashtagSearchResult}</p>
  </div>
)

const FormikApp = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues() {
    return {
      hashtag: "",
      hashtagSearchResult: [], // 
    }
  },
  handleSubmit(values) {
    console.log("$ Search button clicked!")
    let hashtag = values.hashtag
    let hashtagResult = []
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + hashtag + "/"
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      let hashtags = searchHashtags(res.data)
      ...
      console.log("$ Hashtag result - " + hashtagResult)
      values.hashtagSearchResult = hashtagResult;
    })
    ...
})(FormComponent)
```

Comment: Looking from the code posted, maybe it should be `values.hashtagSearchResult = hashtagResult`

Comment: I actually did that too. It isn't fetching the data right away. I had to click on the Search button twice in order for data to populate on UI :( @IonD.Filho

Comment: Did a simple demo with your code, made handle submit be async and handled axios with await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a little modification on your code: @Pavan

The main thing I did was to use setSubmitting(true);

I also add a onSubmit={handleSubmit} to the form

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { withFormik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import axios from "axios";

const FormComponent = ({ values, errors, handleSubmit }) => (
  <div>
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label># </label>
      <Field className="HashtagInput" type="text" name="hashtag" />
      <button className="SearchBtn" type="submit">
        search
      </button>
    </Form>
    <p className="SearchResult">{values.hashtagSearchResult.toString()}</p>
  </div>
);

const FormikApp = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues() {
    return {
      hashtag: "",
      hashtagSearchResult: [] //
    };
  },
  async handleSubmit(values, { setSubmitting }) {
    console.log("$ Search button clicked!");
    let hashtag = values.hashtag;

    setSubmitting(true);
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + hashtag + "/";
    const c = await axios.get(url);

    console.log("$ update");
    values.hashtagSearchResult = [...values.hashtagSearchResult, c.data.title];

    setSubmitting(false);
  }
})(FormComponent);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<FormikApp />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-lake-p8cf2